# How do I solve $\lim_{x \to 1} (\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x^3-1})$ indeterminate limit without the L'hospital rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've been trying to solve this limit without L'Hospital's rule as homework. So I tried rationalizing the denominator and numerator but it didn't work.

My best was: $\lim_{x \to 1} (\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x^3-1}) = \lim_{x \to 1} (\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}) = \lim_{x \to 1} (\frac{x^2+x+1-2}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}) = \lim_{x \to 1} (\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}) = \lim_{x \to 1} (\frac{x+2}{(x^2+x+1)}) = 3 ???$

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I believe the +1 should be there

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I wonder why? $x^2+x+1-2=x^2+x-1\neq (x-1)(x+2)$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! The limit doesn't exist.

Comment: The limit is undefined (unsigned infinite).

Comment: I think your work is fine, and you just need to establish that the second limit in your final answer is indeterminate (could be either $\infty$ or $-\infty$ unless you decide what direction you are going to approach $x = 1$ from). In fact you can do this just by dividing numerator and denominator by $x-1$ and not splitting into two limits.

Comment: The limit just doesn't exist. The limit from the left will be $-\infty$ and from the right that will be $+\infty$.

Comment: The first line is good. Immediately from that you can conclude the thing goes bad as $x\to 1$.

Comment: $x^2+x-1$ is not equal to $(x-1)(x+2)$, so the problem is easier than that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You can see that (x-1) is not a factor of $x^2+x-1$ by putting $x=1$ which gives $1$ and not $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picking up from your second step...

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2+x+1-2}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2+x-1}{(x^3-1)}$$

Let $x\to1$ and find the limit is unbounded or does not exist.

Comment: How do you see it without computer?

Comment: @deadbeef The numerator is positive in a neighborhood of $1$ (do you see why?); the denominator goes to $0$ and is negative in a left neighborhood of $1$, while it is positive in a right neighborhood. So the limit is $-\infty$ from the left and $\infty$ from the right. No computer needed.

Comment: Ok. I see it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Partial fractions save the day:

$$\frac{2}{x^3-1} = \frac{a}{x-1} + \frac{bx+c}{x^2+x+1}$$

You get $a=\frac{2}{3}$, so:

$$\frac{2}{x^3-1} =\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{bx+c}{x^2+x+1}$$

Now $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{bx+c}{x^2+x+1} = \frac{b+c}{3}.$$

So you only need to compute $$\lim_{x\to 1} \left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$. Therefore multiply $\frac{1}{x-1}$ by 1 in the form $\frac{x^2 + x + 1}{x^2 + x + 1}$ and combine the fractions as $\frac{(x^2 + x + 1) - 2}{(x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)} = \frac{x^2 + x -1}{(x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)}$.  The numerator is now going to $1 + 1 - 1 = 1$, while the denominator is going to $(1-1)(1 + 1 + 1) = (0)(3) = 0$.  Notice that $1/0$ is not an indeterminant form. Notice that if we look at the limit from the right, 
$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x^2 + x -1}{(x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)}$, the top is going to $1$, while the bottom is going to $0$ through positive values, so the limit evaluates to $+\infty$.  Checking the limit from the right in the same way,
the top is still going to $1$, but the bottom is going to $0$ through negative values, so the limit evaluates to $-\infty$.  The limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

this limit doesn't exist since $$\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x^3-1}=\frac{x^2+x-1}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}$$